# Compromised account or childish "I was there" graffiti?

Tags: support, spam, security

I just seen this weird answer while doing some reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30735168/317266

[**Edit**: being that bad, the answer seems to have being rapidly plonked via downscoring]

While having a low reputation, the [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4504118/your-mother) seems to have posted some legit questions. But the bio make me think the author might suffering a hijacked/compromised account.

BTW, I don't even find a suitable tag concerning abuse a/o account hijacking.

Comment: If you are his mother, please contact us. Lol

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I've logged them out, in case they left themselves at a public terminal, and temporarily suspended their account until they respond. We occasionally see this with university students or those using shared public terminals.

There's a bit of history here, so I suspect this isn't due to a compromised account. I'll give them the benefit of the doubt, though.

Comment: Good to know that an moderator can log you out if need be.

Comment: I'm rather surprised.

Comment: Maybe you can make us aware when our account is logged from more than one place? This will solve the problem.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky - Only if you can opt-out. I'm always logged in at work, at home (laptop and desktop PC), on my phone, on my tablet, etc. It could become quite annoying.

Comment: @That1Guy gmail does it quite well without being annoying.

Comment: @That1Guy I think it would just be a list of all the devices that your account is logged in on. I think that would be helpful.

Comment: @Zack Yeah, that's not a bad idea.

Comment: I can confirm that friends can mess with SO accounts. My friend thought it would hilarious to post a 'How does I build a facebook, please help' question from my open account. Needless to say, it was flagged relentlessly and removed. Lesson learned, logout.

Comment: @That1Guy That's some serious SO problem. By saying `make us aware when our account is logged from more than one place`, I meant something like when you press on the StackOverflow at the top bar, you will be able to understand that you are logged from more than one place. Or keep a counter at the top bar. It's not that annoying.